# How do you pass data from a controller to a model with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model

How do you pass data from a controller to a model?

In my `application_controller` I grab the user's location (state and city) and include a `before_filter` to make it accesible in all my controllers via

```
before_filter :community

def community
    @city = request.location.city
    @state = request.location.state
    @community = @city+@state
  end
```

Then I try add the data retrieved in the controller to the model via:

```
before_save :add_community

def add_community
      self.community = @community
    end
```

The data, however, never makes its way from the controller to the model. If I use:

```
def add_community
    @city = request.location.city
    @state = request.location.state
    @community = @city+@state
    self.community = @community
  end
```

The methods `request.location.city` and `request.location.state` do not function from the model. I know that everything else is working because if I define `@city` and `@state` as strings, under `def_community`, then everything works, except I don't have a dynamic variable, just a string placed in the model. Also, I know the requests are working in the controller/views, because I can get them to display the proper dynamic info. The issue is simply getting the data from the controller to the model. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question or your other one, since they're essentially the same. Next time, if you want to make things clearer, you can just edit your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236645/getting-methods-that-work-in-controller-views-to-function-in-a-model-ruby-on-ra

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote all answers that you find useful, including answers to others' questions. "Check" (select) the best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concept you're wrestling with is [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which is about separating responsibilities. The models should handle interaction with the DB (or other backend) without needing any knowledge of the context they're being used in (whether it be a an HTTP request or otherwise), views should not need to know about the backend, and controllers handle interactions between the two.

So in the case of your Rails app, the views and controllers have access to the `request` object, while your models do not. If you want to pass information from the current request to your model, it's up to your controller to do so. I would define your `add_community` as follows:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def add_community(city, state)
    self.community = city.to_s + state.to_s  # to_s just in case you got nils
  end

end
```

And then in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create  # I'm assuming it's create you're dealing with
    ...
    @user.add_community(request.location.city, request.location.state)
    ...
  end
end
```

I prefer not to pass the `request` object directly, because that really maintains the separation of the model from the current request. The `User` model doesn't need to know about `request` objects or how they work. All it knows is it's getting a `city` and a `state`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Laser Glad to hear it :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

The class instance variables (those that start with @) in the controllers are separate from those in the models. This is the Model vs the Controller in MVC architecture. The Model and Controller (and view) are separated.

You move info from a controller to a model explicitly. In Rails and other object oriented systems, you have several options:

**Use function parameters**

```
# In the controller
user = User.new(:community => @community)

# In this example, :community is a database field/column of the 
# User model
```

[Docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

**Use instance variables attribute setters**

```
# In the controller
user = User.new
user.community = @community
# same as above, :community is a database field
```

**Passing data to models when the data is not a database field**

```
# In the model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :community
  # In this example, :community is NOT a database attribute of the 
  # User model. It is an instance variable that can be used
  # by the model's calculations. It is not automatically stored in the db

# In the controller -- Note, same as above -- the controller 
# doesn't know if the field is a database attribute or not. 
# (This is a good thing)
user = User.new
user.community = @community
```

[Docs](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html)