# Unable to access controller variables in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following controller

```
class PaypalOrdersController < Spree::BaseController

def new
    @paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new
end

def create
    @order1 = current_order
    @paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(params[:paypal_order])
    if @paypal_order.save
      if @paypal_order.purchase
         render :action => "success"
      else
         render :action => "failure"
      end
    else
       render :action => "new"
    end
end
end
```

and the corresponding model is:

```
class PaypalOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'paypal_payment'
  belongs_to :order

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

  validate :validate_card, :on => :create

  def purchase
    orderHash = @order1.clone
    paypalHash = @paypal_order.clone
    PaypalPayment.new(orderHash, paypalHash)
  end

  private
  def validate_card
    #some code
  end

  def credit_card
    #some code
  end

end
```

When the purchase method is triggered I'm getting the error `cannot clone nil class`. On debugging I found that `@order1` and `@paypal_order` both are nil in the `purchase` method. I am not sure why this is happening. Please can someone explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

controller:

```
PaypalOrder.purchase @order1, @paypal_order
```

model:

```
def self.purchase order, paypal_order
 orderHash = order.clone
 paypalHash = paypal_order.clone
 PaypalPayment.new(orderHash, paypalHash)
end
```

edit:
[How do you pass data from a controller to a model with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237388/how-do-you-pass-data-from-a-controller-to-a-model-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Yes, I understand that this can be done. But it need not be. Model should be able to access controller variables, even without passing them. I fail to understand why the variables become nil inside the purchase method

Comment: No, controller variables should NOT be accessible in Models. Yes there are workarounds, but it breaks the MVC concept of rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

controller

```
if @paypal_order.purchase @order1
```

model

```
def purchase order1
  orderHash = order1.clone
  paypalHash = self.clone        
  PaypalPayment.new(orderHash, paypalHash)
end
```

Comment: This would work. But this should not be needed. Model's method should be able to access controller variables directly