# How can access session variable from controller to model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, session-variables

I used session variable were **session[:parent]** on controller and I want to these variable pass to model. How do pass a params from controller to model?

Here my controller.rb file

```
def new
  @child = Child.new
  @child.pickup_people.build
  @classes =  [['Infant', 0], ['Toddlers', 1], ['Early learners', 2], ['Pre school', 3], ['Pre kindergarten', 4]]
  @parent_types =  [['Father', 'father'], ['Mother', 'mother'], ['Other', 'other']]
  @martial_status = [['Married', 'married'], ['Single', 'single'], ['Divorced', 'divorced'], ['Separated', 'separated'], ['Widowed', 'widowed'], ['Other', 'other']]
  @parent = Parent.new

 #parents those will be mapped with child, here mentioned to show in form page after creation

 if session[:parent_id] != nil
   @parent_sessions = Parent.where(:id => session[:parent_id])
 end
end

def create
  logger.debug "\033[31mI am here\033[31m"
  @child = Child.new(child_params)
  if current_user.has_role? :day_care
    @child.day_care_id = current_user.day_care.id
  elsif current_user.has_role? :director
    @child.day_care_id = current_user.director.day_care.id
  elsif current_user.has_role? :assistant_director
    @child.day_care_id = current_user.assistant_director.day_care.id
  elsif current_user.has_role? :teacher
    @child.day_care_id = current_user.teacher.day_care.id
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @child.save
    #        logger.debug "\033[31m#{session[:parent_id]}\033[31m"
      if session[:parent] != nil
        session[:parent].each do |p|
          Relative.create(:child_id => @child.id, :parent_id => p["id"].to_i, :parent_type => p["type"])
        end
      end
    ####
      gflash :success => "Child was succesfully created."
      format.html { redirect_to @child }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @child }
      session[:parent] = nil
      session[:parent_id] = nil

      logger.debug "\033[31mdestroyed#{session[:parent_id]}\033[31m"
    else
      gflash :error => "Unable to create, please try again."
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @child.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what the problem with your question is, I don't see anything wrong, have you tried it?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10237527/707636. Probably you'll get some idea. Also it would great if you could provide more details like, what you want to pass to model?

Comment: i want to pass session[:parent] to model

Answer (score 0):

Models are an interface to the database. They can be used without a session (e.g. from IRB). It would be a violation of MVC to allow the models to talk to the session. So the session object is not visible in models. Either pass it as a parameter to a method in your model or define a method in your model which returns what you want and then store it in the session (from your controller).

**For e.g.**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def item_status
    return :no_such_item
  end
end
```

In your controller

```
session[:item_status] = current_user.item_status
```

I hope it makes you clear...