# Rails render json including methods with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this render in a method controller:

```
render :json => @boats, :include => {:port => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:city => {:only => [:id, :name], :methods => :translatedCity}}}}
```

but `translatedCity` method in the model should accept language parameter.

```
  def translatedCity     
    language = params[:language]
    puts "translatedCity.language=" + language  
    city = TranslationService.translateCity(self.city_id, language)        
    return city.element_translation
  end
```

I have the parameter in the controller. Is there any way to pass this parameter to the method in the model?

Comment: translatedCity  would need to accept a parameter like so translatedCity(language) in order for you to have access to the value in params[:language] only the controller has access to the params hash.
read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237388/how-do-you-pass-data-from-a-controller-to-a-model-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All answers are good!

I just did something like:

In controller:

```
boat.port.language = params[:language]
```

In model:

```
attr_accessor :language
  @language  

  def translatedCity            
    city = TranslationService.translateCity(self.city_id, language)        
    return city.element_translation
  end
```

What do you think?

Comment: Seems reasonable. I feel funny adding temporary request data to a model so that later I can call an instance method, but to each their own :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the process of passing methods that require params `to_json` is not nicely built into rails. a typical pattern is to modify the `as_json` method on the model to accept custom keys, and then calling `to_json` (or `render :json`)

```
# city.rb model
def translatedCity(language)
  puts "translatedCity.language=" + language  
  city = TranslationService.translateCity(self.city_id, language)        
  return city.element_translation
end

def as_json(options = {})
  json_to_return = super
  if options.has_key? :translatedCity
    city_translation = self.translatedCity(options[:translatedCity][:language])
    json_to_return[:translatedCity] = city_translation
  end

  return json_to_return
end
```

now in your controller you pass everything in accoringdly

```
render :json => @boats, 
  :include => {
    :port => {
      :only => [:id, :name], 
      :include => {
        :city => {
          :only => [:id, :name], 
          :translatedCity => params[:language]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`as_json` doesn't support methods that require arguments, but this is a good place to use a Presenter (or Decorator, or View Model, depending who you talk to) that builds the JSON you want. [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) is a gem that helps with that if you want one, and your controller would look something like

```
data = @boats.map do |boat|
  BoatPresenter.new(boat).as_json(language: params[:language])
end
render json: data
```

Then `BoatPresenter` would add the extra data you want in its `as_json`:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  @boat.as_json(options).tap do |json|
    json[:translated_city] = @boat.translated_city(options[:language])
  end
end
```

You can also have `BoatPresenter` add your default `include`s, etc. if you want a standard set without the controller having to worry about it. And if you don't want to do the array mapping yourself, Draper also offers collection presenters (eg `BoatsPresenter`).

---

If you're averse to adding a class, you could also override `as_json` directly on `Boat` to handle a `language` option:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(options).tap do |json|
    json[:translated_city] = translated_city(options[:language])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'language' in a session variable and set it before executing to_json in your controller, and destroy session in your method before return as follwoing

```
def translatedCity(language=nil)
    language ||= session[:language]
    puts "translatedCity.language=" + language  
    city = TranslationService.translateCity(self.city_id, language)        
    session[:language] = nil #destroy session, or use session.delete(:language)         
    return city.element_translation
end


session[:language] = language
render :json => @boats, :include => {:port => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:city => {:only => [:id, :name], :methods => :translatedCity}}}}
```

Comment: is that cool to save this kind of data in session? I mean we can need more data to pass in the same kind of parameters, what do you think?